Short story - Protagonist is a young boy whose parents traveled in Africa. He had leprosy (now cured) and is socially awkward
The story was one of an anthology I read in the 1990s, I think, from a book discarded by the local community college. I remember several of the books were by T. Coraghessan Boyle (must have had a teacher who was assigning them) so it might have been one of his short stories. The protagonist is a young male, I think around middle or high school age. My memory is that he was Caucasian. His parents were some sort of explorers or missionaries, which led to him growing up abroad, including in jungles, but they'd moved back to the United States. He's socially awkward, in part because the kids know he has leprosy (treated and not affecting him) and in part because he acts unusually due to growing up traveling with his parents. I remember a scene where he was chasing (being chased?) by some of the kids, and he grabs a branches and swings himself up to the top of it (I remember him referring to it as being able to do Tarzan stuff due to growing up in the jungle) and then dropping down beside (onto?) one of the kids chasing him to explain that his leprosy is treated, and no longer contagious.
The short story was in English, probably less than 30 pages long. Unfortunately, I remember almost nothing else about it.

When I read your title, I understood 'he has treated leprosy' to mean ''he has given other people treatment for leprosy'.

Fixed. I honestly don't remember if he was being treated for the leprosy, or the treatment had completed and he no longer has it. It's been decades.
